# How does one identify if Oracle Data Guard is enabled in Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

How does one identify if the Oracle Data Guard feature is enabled in Oracle database?

If this can be determined by a query, what is the query for finding the same?

Comment: May i use this query for the same  "select distinct status,type from v$archive_dest_status where status='VALID'"

Answer (score 3):

There is a built-in procedure for that.

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  feature_boolean number;
  aux_count number;
  feature_info clob;
begin
  dbms_feature_data_guard(feature_boolean, aux_count, feature_info);
  dbms_output.put_line(feature_boolean);
  dbms_output.put_line(feature_info);
end;
/
```

Sample output when Data Guard is not used:

```
0
Data Guard usage not detected
```

Sample output when Data Guard is used:

```
1
Number of standbys: 1, Redo Apply used: TRUE, SQL Apply used: FALSE, Snapshot
Standby used: FALSE, Broker used: TRUE, Protection mode: MAXIMUM PERFORMANCE,
Log transports used: LGWR ASYNC, Fast-Start Failover used: FALSE, Real-Time
Apply used: TRUE, Compression used: FALSE, Flashback used: FALSE
```

The source of the above procedure is not wrapped, so one can browse it and find how the database detects Data Guard usage.

```
-- check for Data Guard usage by counting valid standby destinations
execute immediate 'select count(*) from v$archive_dest ' ||
    'where status = ''VALID'' and target = ''STANDBY'''
    into num_standbys;

if (num_standbys > 0) then
    feature_boolean := 1;
```

Basically, if the result of this query is greater than 0, than the Data Guard is in use as per the procedure:

```
select count(*) from v$archive_dest where status = 'VALID' and target = 'STANDBY';
```

Comment: In my case  am in the need to use query to find the result. please suggest me the queries

Comment: @Velkumar Added a query.

Comment: May i use this query for the same  "select distinct status,type from v$archive_dest_status where status='VALID'"   From this i can assume database as dataguard if the type is any one of this PHYSICAL,LOGICAL,SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT NAME,VERSION,CURRENTLY_USED,FEATURE_INFO
FROM DBA_FEATURE_USAGE_STATISTICS
WHERE NAME = 'Data Guard'
```

Comment: But this query does not output cascade standby from Primary and 1st Standby instead only from Cascade Standby.

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlplus / as sysdba

show parameter LOG_ARCHIVE_CONFIG
```

if output is blank, it means Data Guard is not configured.